# Jasmine Unit testing HttpInterceptor validating method argument

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an Angular (6) HttpInterceptor like with this intercept method:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>,next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (this.translationService.currentLang) {
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Accept-Language': this.translationService.currentLang
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

How can I get this to unit test with jasmine and check that the returned request contains the new header? I know I can get the parameter with

```
let next = jasmine.createSpyObj('httpHandler', ['handle']);
next.handle.calls.mostRecent();
```

But how can I validate that the header is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I used to test some interceptor:

```
describe(`interceptor: yourinterceptor`, () => { // CHANGE HERE
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let injector: TestBed;

  function createTestModule(providers: Provider[] = []) {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: YOUR_INTERCEPTOR, // CHANGE HERE
          multi: true
        },
        ...providers
      ]
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    // empty
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  describe('request with headers', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      createTestModule();
    });
    it('should make the request with headers', inject([HttpClient], (http: HttpClient) => {
      http.get('/dummy').subscribe();
      const httpRequest: TestRequest = httpMock.expectOne('/dummy');
      expect(httpRequest.request.headers.has("YOUR_HEADER")).toBeTruthy(); // CHANGE HERE

    }));
  });
});
```

Comment: That helped me. Thank you!